# Is Tendermint proof-of-stake?

Tags: consensus, proof-of-stake

I couldn't understand if this tendermint protocol is proof-of-stake or something like proof-of-lock?

https://tendermint.com/static/docs/tendermint.pdf

Comment: What is proof-of-lock? Vlad Zamfir [refers to](https://medium.com/@Vlad_Zamfir/the-history-of-casper-chapter-3-70fefb1182fc) Temdermint as "a security-deposit based proof-of-stake system".

Comment: @SergeiTikhomirov Since you have to deposit or "lock" your coins I thought maybe it is called something other than PoS. In Ethereum's PoS I think all coins are eligible for PoS, and there is no concept of "locking". Although I didn't research it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like Proof-of-Stake or at least something very similar, and suffers from similar issues, for example:

> Note that this does not preclude a 2/3 majority of validators from publishing a blockchain fork after they had unbonded and sold their coins to an unsuspecting party. This is called a long-range double-spend attack. A user can
>   avoid long-range attacks by syncing their blockchain periodically within the bounds of the unbonding period.